# (Font identification) Jagged, cornery uppercase font

Tags: font-identification

I’m helping a former colleague redo her website (and moving it to a host that doesn’t charge outrageous prices like the one they’re using now does). Their current website was originally done by someone at some ad agency—they don’t even really know who themselves, so contacting the original designer isn’t an option, unfortunately.

Their original logo and colour palette are quite distinctive, and I quite like them, so I’d like to keep using them. Unfortunately, I can’t figure out what the font used in the logo is. There’s not much to go by, as it’s only two words in all-caps, but the font is very distinctive, so I figure someone here might recognise it.

I’ve tried WhatTheFont and other usual suspects, but the closest match I’ve been able to get there is [Scriber](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/northernblock/scriber/). Not a bad match, but also clearly not the actual font used.

Does anyone here happen to know this font? (Or perhaps if it even *is* a font, rather than just drawn manually in Illustrator?)

*Note: I don’t know, obviously, if the font is uppercase-only, or if the designer just used all-caps in the logo.*

### Distinctive features

- The sharp corners instead of curves throughout
- The downwards slanting [spine](http://www.typographydeconstructed.com/spine/) on the S (unlike Scriber)
- The width of the S
- The tail-style spur on the G (also unlike Scriber), curving away from the hip

### The Logo

[image: Site logo]

(Yes, I will be adding the missing apostrophe when I redo the site.)

Comment: Have you tried the [dafont.com font identification forum](http://www.dafont.com/forum/?f=1)? I have a feeling they could identify this easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

99% percent sure that's [Gridnik:](https://www.fonts.com/font/the-foundry/foundry-gridnik)
[image]

Comment: I’m 100% sure you’re right—that is it exactly, right down to the last detail. Thank you!